# Re-implement the AVX2 intrincs using asm code

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, avx2

Greeting everyone. 
Due to some special reason, we have to re-implement the AVX2 intrics like the following way:

```
static __inline __m256i __attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__))
    _xmm256_and_si256(__m256i s1, __m256i s2){

    __m256i result;

    __asm__ ("vpand %2, %1, %0": "=r"(result): "rm" "s1", "rm" "s2" ) ;
    // sorry, this statement does not work

    return result; 
}
```

Corresponding function is `_mm256_and_si256(__m256i s1, __m256i s2)`, which is an AVX2 intrincs.
After some search through google, I found some simililar such as connect some base type like `int`, `float` and `long` to input registers. 
However, I still didn't find the way to connect the input parameters `s1` and `s2` to the input registers `ymm1` and `ymm2` which are used for the asm `vpand` code.

So anyone here is willing to help me to make the above example work?
Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `r` constraint is for general purpose registers, and your asm block has wrong syntax anyway. The appropriate constraint for avx is `x`, and also mind that only one operand can be in memory (although that could be either one, which this template doesn't handle). Furthermore the `nodebug` attribute doesn't seem to exist.

As such, something like this will work better:

```
__attribute__((always_inline)) inline __m256i
_xmm256_and_si256(__m256i s1, __m256i s2)
{
    __m256i result;
    __asm__ ("vpand %2, %1, %0" : "=x"(result) : "x"(s1), "xm"(s2) );
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean no offense. But I tried to compile following program. The error message is "root@debian:~/code# c++ avx2-wrapper-test.cc 
fatal error: error in backend: Do not know how to split the result of this operator!
clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)". I am using clang++ -v
Debian clang version 3.5.0-10 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0).

Comment: Not sure what you did, it [works online with 3.5.0](http://goo.gl/kDemyF). Even though gcc generates better code.

Comment: I think I have got your idea and found out what is wrong. Thank you again for this great answer and this amazing online tool!